printer hp Smart Tank 5100 works with USB, but not with wifi
When I run $ hp-setup for setting up my new printer with wifi connection, hp-setup can find my printer and I can print and scan by USB cable, but I cannot run it over wifi. When I run hp-setup and choose the third option (Wireless/802.11), I can select my printer, which is the only entry in the list, but I come to an error.
The error message in the occurring dialog window says: ”An I/O error occurred.
Please check the USB connection to your printer and try again.
(Device I/O error)“. The terminal output:
$ hp-setup

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.23.12)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching on USB bus...
error: Channel write error
error:  An I/O error occurred.  Please check the USB connection to your printer and try again. (Device I/O error)

Done.

When I choose the second option (direct connection or JetDirect), I get the error message: ”HPLIP cannot detect printers in your network.
This may be due to existing firewall settings blocking the required ports. When you are in a trusted network environment, you may open the ports for network services like mdns and slp in the firewall. For detailed steps follow the link. https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/KnowledgeBase/Troubleshooting/TroubleshootNetwork“ and cannot choose my printer, which isn't found by hp-setup.
Doing this interactively leads to the following.
$ hp-setup -i

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.23.12)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)


--------------------------------
| SELECT CONNECTION (I/O) TYPE |
--------------------------------

  Num       Connection  Description                                               
            Type                                                                  
  --------  ----------  ----------------------------------------------------------
  0*        usb         Universal Serial Bus (USB)                                
  1         net         Network/Ethernet/Wireless (direct connection or JetDirect)

Enter number 0...1 for connection type (q=quit, enter=usb*) ? 1

Using connection type: net

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.

My first thought was that the USB cable doesn't work properly, but I can print and scan without any problem.
Any suggestions what could cause the error or how I get the correct ip address of my printer?
EDIT I got the IP address by using nmtui to change the wifi connection to the printer, followed by ip r, ip a and hp-setup (with the second option), which gave me several ip addresses (but all lead to the same result and output).
Trying hp-makeuri for setting up the printer's IP leads to the following.
$ hp-makeuri 192.168.223.1

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.23.12)
Device URI Creation Utility ver. 5.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

error: Device not found


This question is similar to: Finding the printer's IP address. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
